# reverse timestamp

Tags: c#, timestamp

I was trying to save some stuff to the Log table with timestamp so I first did this:

```
public static string TimeStamp(
   this DateTime datetime, string timestamptFormat = "yyyyMMddHHmmssffff")
   {
     return datetime.ToString(timestamptFormat);
   }
```

And then I found a snippet like this:

```
static public string ToReverseTimestamp(this DateTime dateTime)
{
return string.Format("{0:10}", DateTime.MaxValue.Ticks - dateTime.Ticks);
}
```

I started wondering what the heck is reverse timestamp is useful for, and came across [this article](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.java.hadoop.hbase.user/20286)

Now my question is: if the second snippet is even correct? And how do you convert it back to "normal" timestamp or how do you get readable datetime information from it?

Comment: That `"{0:10}"` in the format isn't good. I'd recommend just doing `"{0}"`.

Comment: @Joel I demand an explanation, Sir! :)

Comment: Of course. When I run the code with `"{0:10}"`, I get the long value with a 1 in front of it. When I check the standard numeric format strings, "10" isn't one of them. That 1 caused me an `OverflowException` in my `long.Parse`. Going to `"{0}"` fixed the problem.

Comment: Yes.. I just run into that exception too... Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that the `DateTime` is converted to universal time before conversion to avoid time-zone problems:

```
public static string ToReverseTimestamp(this DateTime dateTime)
{
    return (long.MaxValue - dateTime.ToUniversalTime().Ticks).ToString();
}
```

You can convert the value back to a `DateTime` value by parsing the `string` to a `long`, calculating `MaxValue - (MaxValue - x) = x` and constructing a new `DateTime` with `DateTimeKind.Utc` from `x`:

```
public static DateTime FromReverseTimestamp(string timestamp)
{
    return new DateTime(long.MaxValue - long.Parse(timestamp), DateTimeKind.Utc);
}
```

*Example:*

```
var input = DateTime.Now;                      // {17/05/2012 16:03:17} (Local)
var timestamp = ToReverseTimestamp(input);     // "2520650302020786038"
var result = FromReverseTimestamp(timestamp);  // {17/05/2012 18:03:17} (Utc)
```

Comment: Interesting. What would be the purpose of a Reverse Timestamp?

Comment: but why are you doing toUTC, should't you then apply the same for the first DateTime as well?

Comment: @Agzam: It doesn't matter, as long as you use the same value in `FromReverseTimestamp`.

Comment: no I mean, shouldn't it be like this:  `DateTime.MaxValue.ToUniversalTime().Ticks - dateTime.ToUniversalTime().Ticks`

Comment: `FromReverseTimestamp` throws an exception

Comment: DateTime.MaxValue.ToUniversalTime() is bad. Could potentially go past DateTime.MaxValue, at which point it would be set equal to DateTime.MaxValue. (Easy to test if in US. Otherwise, might have to change your time zone to test)

Comment: @jp2code - Follow the link in the original question. Gives a good example of the purpose of a reverse timestamp.

Comment: Got it. Used for sorting, then.